# Azure App Configuration variables are not available in startup on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, azure-app-configuration

I ran into a problem with retrieving configuration from Azure App Configuration in Startup methods.

```
public static IConfigurationSection GetAuthSection()
{
    var intermediateConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true).Build();
    var appConfiguration = intermediateConfig["AppConfigurationConnectionString"];

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appConfiguration))
    {
        builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(opt =>
        {
            opt.Connect(appConfiguration).Select("Tool*");
        });
    }
    
    var configRoot = builder.Build();
    var debugConfig = configRoot.GetDebugView();
    return configRoot.GetSection("Tool:Auth");
}
```

`GetDebugView` method returns such string that is OK for me.

```
Tool:
  Auth:
    CallbackPath=***
    ClientId=***
    ClientSecret=***
    Instance=***
    Scopes=***
    SignedOutCallbackPath=***
    TenantId=***
```

But method `GetSection` returns null in `Value` property.

Method `GetAuthSection` is used in Startup.cs in method `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(ConfigurationLoader.GetAuthSection());
    
    ...
}
```

I can't hold Auth data in the local config due to some reasons. After the server is built and it is running these data can be retrieved from the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use method `AddEnvironmentVariables` to transfer data from `AzureAppConfigurationProvider` to `IConfiguration`